# Access inner variables from external functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to access an inner variable from an external function like this example?

```
function a(f) {
  var c = 'test';
  f();
}

a(function() {
  alert(c);  //at this point, c should = "test"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that won't work. What matters is where (lexically) a function is **defined**, not where it's **invoked.**

When figuring out what (if anything) "c" refers to, the language looks in the local scope, then in the next scope out *based on the definition of the function*.  Thus if that invocation of "a" took place in *another* function that *did* have its own local "c", then that value would be what the alert showed.

```
function b() {
  var c = 'banana';
  a(function() {
    alert(c);  
  });
}

b(); // alert will show "banana"
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.  The scope you declare your anonymous function in does not have access to this `c` variable -- in fact, **nothing but `a` will ever has access to `c`**.

Answer (score 2):

No this will not work because the variable `c` is defined within the function and is not available outside of the function.  One option though is to pass the variable `c` into the function provided to `a`

```
function a(f) { 
  var c = 'test'; 
  f(c); 
} 

a(function(c) { 
  alert(c);  //at this point, c should = "test" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this isn't possible. You can

**1.** Declare the `c` variable outside of the scope of the function

**2.** Pass an argument to `f`:

```
function a(f) { var c = { name: 'test' }; f(c)  };
a(function(o) { alert(o.name) })
```