# Hack the JS: Thoughts on mixing in some object as arguments (or inner variables) for external functions (like **kwargs) w/o using this

Tags: javascript, scope

There's a truly a lot of questions that seem similar to this on SO, but in fact every of those questions is for a little bit about different things. And also I know, the things I describe are a hacking and unrecommended way, but in my case it is really required (code size REALLY matters for me, every five bytes matter):

What I have is the object that dynamically filled with some variables (I prepare it for internal usage, but it filled with variables defined by user):

```
var scope = { 'a': 0, 'b': 12, 'c': 64 };
```

And, I have a user-defined anonymous function that needs access to this scope directly, without using `this` (I'd really prefer it)<del>, and it is defined *not* in my `var`-scope</del>:

```
function anonymousFunc() { // user don't knows any names of arguments
  console.log(a, b, c); // I expect '0, 12, 64'
}
```

In fact, `scope` is not even an object, but a complex array that stores levels of contexts, so to be true, actually it looks more like this: `[ { 'a': 0 }, { 'b': 12, 'c': 64 } ]`, and then I choose the level for a concrete function to access. And, to be even more truthful, I have several objects like this to mix into a function scope.

So the best another way to do w/o hacking (`eval` or `with`) (OOP way) I see, is to make user act like this:

```
(function() {

    function prepareAndCall(f) {
        c = this.ctx[level];
        l = currentLabels();
        m = makeChunk();
        f();
    }

    var c, l, m; 

    // it is injected from user code
    function anonymousFunc() {
        console.log(c.a, c.b, l.g, m.pos);
    }

    prepareAndCall(anonymousFunc);

})();
```

But what I want is to free user from thinking about where he needs to take these variables. I can mix them in one object, but it will also be not a fine-fitting thing in my case, most of these variables are defined by user himself in an external place, so he expects to have them in his scope directly and I'd like if he don't knows anything about those `c`-`m`-`l` variables, even if it is just a `c`. I want to emulate that he has these variables on hands. And he knows that he may accidentally redefine them.

---

So, I found some methods:

One [With eval, and it requires a string-source of function](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1927-Faking-Context-In-Javascript-s-Function-Constructor.htm)

<sub>(**Upd.**, I removed the [previous bad example](http://jsfiddle.net/MYmHx/) **after** [@Gijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713326/gijs) comment and updated it with new one)</sub>

And second one is *polluting the global context* ([at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpCq4/2/))

```
(function(global_ctx) { 

    // here is the user context, variables
    // defined here are accessible to user 

    var __g = global_ctx;
    __g.__test_var = 5;
    if (__test_var !== 5) alert('__g is not global context');

    var __f = (function() {

        // here is the inner context, variables
        // defined here are not accessible to user   

        var scope = [
            { a: 16 },
            { oo: 12 },
            { b: 17, c: 20 } 
        ]; 

        function callUserFunc(f) {
            //console.log('call user func');
            loadVars(__g, 2);
            f();
        }
        // __g.__f = callUserFunc;

        function loadVars(g, level) {
            for (name in scope[level]) {
                g[name] = scope[level][name];
            }
        }

        return callUserFunc;

    })();

    if (typeof scope !== 'undefined') alert('scope is visible, error');
    if (typeof loadVars !== 'undefined') alert('loadVars is visible, error');

    __f(function() { // user function will be inserted here
        if (typeof oo !== 'undefined') alert('user function sees what it must not see');
        alert(b + ', ' + c);
    }); 

})(this);
```

---

As a result, I think it is probably not a question, but more a subject to discuss: Is it really a bad way to use `with` or `eval` *in this case*? Because I don't know any other way to do it like this.

Related Literature:

- [Faking Context In Javascript's Function() Constructor](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1927-Faking-Context-In-Javascript-s-Function-Constructor.htm)
- [Using The WITH Keyword With Javascript's Function() Constructor](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1929-Using-The-WITH-Keyword-With-Javascript-s-Function-Constructor.htm)
- [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)
- [Functions and Execution Contexts in JavaScript](http://blog.tuenti.com/dev/functions-and-execution-contexts-in-javascript-2/)
- [Sugarless - A Functional & Context Oriented way to write JavaScript](http://laktek.com/2011/12/21/introducing-sugarless/)
- [Access inner variables from external functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248286/access-inner-variables-from-external-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is modify the scope in which the user-given function runs. The problem is that a function's scope [cannot be modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Functions) (in link: "these scope objects cannot be directly accessed from your JavaScript code"); you can modify the binding of `this` using `.call` and `.apply`, but this is not the same as modifying the enclosing scope.

There are only three exceptions to this rule that I know of:

1. The global scope object (in a browser environment, usually `window`, or a DOM Worker scope (`self`) (!)). Because this is the global scope, you know where it is and you can change it, and changes to it will affect code that runs within the same global scope.
2. Declaring it inside a `with` block [outside of ES5 strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description)
3. Using `eval` [outside of ES5 strict](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/10/new-es5-strict-mode-support-new-vars-created-by-strict-mode-eval-code-are-local-to-that-code-only/)

Actually, if the user-defined code does not need access to the DOM, DOM Workers might help. In a worker, the global scope is identified as `self`. Unfortunately, `postMessage` only supports strings and JSON-serializable objects, which means functions are out. Which then means you'd have to still pass a string and then call `new Function` or `eval` with it. The upside is that you're relatively isolated from anything the user-generated code would do to mess with your own page (of course this does mean you need to distrust anything you get in `onmessage` and `onerror` handlers...).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my case, Workers also does not fit because I am writing a script to work both in `node.js` and in browser (however, [there is](https://github.com/pgriess/node-webworker) a Workers support library for `node.js`). 

You are absolutely right about isolating, it is much better to leave only `m` (in my example) variable in user scope, I'll correct it.

Comment: I've tested my example a bit more, and it is completely not about `with` (in fact, it failed in a clean environment), it just polluted the global context when I've assigned `m` to `this` and I thought it worked then. So the only way is to push vars in the global context, even without using `with`. So, yes, the 1st point is preferable and fits my case.

Comment: Ah, of course. `with` would need to be used when declaring the function (function scope is determined by declaration, not by assignment or the location of the reference, see closures...). I'll update my answer to clarify. I also just noticed that `with` is also forbidden in ES5 strict...